# Incorrect behavior function annotateImage

Tags: php, image-processing, crop, image-resizing, imagick

I have some bug (or feature).
I want to put multiline text on the center of image.

```
$my_text_lines = ['sssssssss', 'ddddddddd', 'bbbbbbbbbb'];
$background_image = new Imagick(dirname(__FILE__).'/test/img.jpg');

$background_image_1 = $background_image->clone();
$background_image_2 = $background_image->clone();
```

It's function for putting text-blocks in two ways for text and putting green lines for check the correct y-position.

```
function put_text(Imagick $image, $text_lines) {

    $line_height = 70;

    $text_style = new ImagickDraw();
    $text_style->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
    $text_style->setTextEncoding('utf-8');
    $text_style->setFont(dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/skolarpe-webfont.ttf');
    $text_style->setFontSize(40);
    $text_style->setFillOpacity(1);

    $start_y_point = ($image->getImageHeight() - count($text_lines)*$line_height)/2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($text_lines); $i++) {

        $y_point = $start_y_point + $i*$line_height;

        // default put text on image
        $image->annotateImage(
            $text_style,
            50,
            $y_point,
            0,
            $text_lines[$i]
        );

        // other way to put text on image
        $other_text_draw = new ImagickDraw();
        $other_text_draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ff0000'));
        $other_text_draw->setFontSize(30);
        $other_text_draw->setFont(dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/skolarpe-webfont.ttf');
        $other_text_draw->annotation(150, $y_point, $text_lines[$i]);
        $image->drawImage($other_text_draw);

        // test rectangle
        $test_rectangle = new \ImagickDraw();
        $test_rectangle->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#00ff00'));
        $test_rectangle->rectangle(30, $y_point, $image->getImageWidth()-30, $y_point+5);

        $image->drawImage($test_rectangle);

    }

    return $image;

}
```

On original image everything is fine.

```
$background_image_1 = put_text($background_image_1, $my_text_lines);
$background_image_1->writeImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/test/test_imagick_1.jpg');
```

In next case I try to crop image and resize it to original size

```
$background_image_2->cropImage(
    $background_image->getImageWidth()/2,
    $background_image->getImageHeight()/2,
    $background_image->getImageWidth()/4,
    $background_image->getImageHeight()/4);

$background_image_2->resizeImage(
    $background_image->getImageWidth(), 
    $background_image->getImageHeight(), 
    Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);
```

And put text and save it to other file;

```
$background_image_2 = put_text($background_image_2, $my_text_lines);
$background_image_2->writeImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/test/test_imagick_2.jpg');
```

The position of text lines is incorrect (see image below). Why?
How put text on correct position?

I checked image sizes and resolutions.

I have bad solution: to save the image after crop and resize and re-open it.
In this case all fine but it's a very bad solution.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php var_dump($background_image_1->getImageResolution()); ?></td>
        <td><?php var_dump($background_image_2->getImageResolution()); ?></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><?php var_dump(Imagick::getVersion()); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "{$background_image_1->getImageWidth()}x{$background_image_1->getImageHeight()}"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "{$background_image_2->getImageWidth()}x{$background_image_2->getImageHeight()}"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/test/test_imagick_1.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="/test/test_imagick_2.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Look the code on github https://github.com/dkoldyaev/imagick_bug*
[image]